# Use react-redux-grid with redux-saga

Tags: redux-saga

We like the many features of [react-redux-grid](https://github.com/bencripps/react-redux-grid) and are about to evaluate it. We're using [saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) to handle all async REST calls. I have a general question on any advice or suggestions how to use redux-grid with sagas.

Background:
We retrieve the data in our sagas and store them in the redux store and bind the property to the grid (with data). That means we work with "local" data. But since there could be thousands of records, we only retrieve a subset. Pagging for example we solve with a custom pagging component that triggers a new retrieve of data in saga and hence a update of the data property.

Sorting is a bit more of a hack. With redux-grid you can either sort local or sortingSource. Since we only have a subset of all data loaded, local is not an option. We found out, that we can pass a function to "sortingSource" and there it's possible to call the action that triggers saga/data update:

```
const remoteSort = (pageIndex, obj, ordering) => {
  const sort = ordering.sort
  this.props.setOrderBy({
    name: sort.property,
    direction: sort.direction
  })


  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({})
  })
}
```

Grid:

```
<Grid
    columns={this.props.columnDefinitions}
    data={this.props.entities}
    plugins={{
      PAGER: {
        enabled: true,
        pagingType: 'local',
        pagerComponent: (
            <Pagination
                totalRecords={this.props.entityCount}
                recordsPerPage={this.props.limit}
                onPageChange={this.onPageChange}
                currentPage={this.props.currentPage}
            />
        )
      },
      COLUMN_MANAGER: {
        sortable: {
          enabled: true,
          method: 'remote',
          sortingSource: remoteSort
        }
      }
    }}
    stateKey="listViewGrid"
    reducerKeys="grid"
/>
```

It works but IMO this too much of a workaround and we even get a console log warning because of the empty promise.

Now the question: Is there a better way to combine saga with the grid? Of course we could consider rewrite the application to work the way the grid wants (without saga) but in general we are happy with redux-saga.
Any input on the matter is appreciated!

Comment: i created an issue on github: https://github.com/bencripps/react-redux-grid/issues/146